Creating a Migration for DbContext B creates tables for both DbContext B and A
I have a project that has 2 DbContexts and their respective entities.
DbContextA is from a legacy SQLServer and is a "database first" approach.
DbContextB is from a new Postgres server and being used with a "code first" approach.
Both DbContexts are registered at startup the following way:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContextA>(o => o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("database-a")));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContextB>(o => o.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("database-b")));

When I generate a migration with the following command:
dotnet ef migrations add Initial -s .\src\API\API.csproj -p .\src\DAL\DAL.csproj --context DbContextB --output-dir DbContextBMigrations

I get a migration that is going to create all the tables from both DbContexts in the same database. I have no idea why this is happening. Without specifying the DbContext in the command I get an error saying I need to specify one (which makes total sense). I don't understand why it's picking up the DbSets from DbContextA.

Are you sure some entities from DbContextB are not referencing (via navigation properties - both reference  or collection) some entities from DbContextA? Because declaredDbSets are just one of the possible ways of Including types in the model. And once entity is included in the model, it by default is included in the migrations.

Also checked that issue, as some Entities in both DbContexts had the same class name but in different namespaces. Also renamed all entities that had the same name in both DbContexts so there are no repeated class names but the problem persisted. I'm starting to think it's this line on OnModelCreating modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DbContextB).Assembly); It might be also picking up the IEntityTypeConfiguration from the DbContextA entities since they are defined on the same Assembly. Will create a predicate func that filters them based on namespace and see if it's fixed.

Oops, ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly exactly is the issue, I forgot to mention that's another way (similar to modelBuilder.Entity<TClass>()) which registers all the classes as entities in the context where you are calling it. Good catch, glad you solved it!

From reading the comments to your question, it seems that you are using "ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly" to detect your entity configurations.
If those entity configurations are located in the same project, then both DbContexts are going to load all entity configurations. There are two options to fix your issue:

Move your entity configurations for each DbContext in two different projects so that they are not within the same assembly
Explicitly call each entity configuration in the OnModelCreating method of your DbContext

